# Can't show the query result in select option

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, codeigniter

**UPDATE**

I'm working with codeigniter, and i have simple select option like this:

```
<select id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '"  class="form-control no_inv" >
  <?php 
    $jj = "<script>var e = document.getElementById('id_barang').value;document.write(e);</script>"; 
    $noInv = $this->modelku->select_inv($jj); 
  ?> 
    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled>Pilih no inventaris</option> 
  <?php 
    foreach($noInv->result() as $inv){ ?> 
      <option value="<?php echo $inv->no_inv ?>">
        <?php echo $inv->no_inv ?>
      </option><?php } 
   ?>
</select><br>
```

And this is my html element with id = `id_barang`:

```
 <select name="id_barang" id="id_barang" class="form-control">
    <?php $idBarang = $this->modelku->select_idBrang() ?>
    <?php foreach($idBarang->result() as $idBr){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $idBr->id_barang ?>"><?php echo $idBr->id_barang ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select required>
```

`select_inv` function from modelku:

```
public function select_inv($idbrang)
{
    $this->db->select("no_inv");
    $this->db->from('detail_barang');
    $this->db->where('kondisi', 'Ada');
    $this->db->where('id_barang ', $idbrang);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

But when i click the select option, the value from no_inv doesn't appear in my select option?

[image]

Can someone help me pls?

Comment: Try this in your model
$query = $this->db->get();   
$query->result(); //OR $query->result_array()

Comment: <option value="<?php echo $inv['no_inv '] ?>">

Answer (score 1):

the problem lies in using a variable `$idbrang` in the manual written where clause. To use a variable change the line

```
$this->db->where("kondisi = 'Ada' AND id_barang = '$idbrang' ");
```

to

```
$this->db->where('kondisi', 'Ada');
$this->db->where('id_barang ', $idbrang);
```

more info [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

**note:** I gave this answer before the OP was completely remodeled

Comment: Thanks brother, i already try it, but no_inv doesn't appear in my select option

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a value to a PHP variable by using javascript, since they have different times for execution, and when you use the script tag, unless the browser loads it, it will be only a PHP string. I think you'll need to change this to use a PHP value for the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this:

```
<select id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '"  class="form-control no_inv" >
  <?php 
    $jj = "<script>var e = document.getElementById('id_barang').value;document.write(e);</script>"; 
    $noInv = $this->modelku->select_inv($jj); 
  ?>
<!-- // ... -->
</select>
```

Because the content of your PHP `$jj` variable is plain text, it will not select your `#id_barang` value. `$jj` will returns exactly what you put into quotes.

One way to do what you expect is **using Ajax to pass javascript values to a PHP file** using POST/GET methods. [Here are more details](http://www.phpcodify.com/pass-data-to-php-using-ajax-without-page-load/).

This : `id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '"` will not work too because you're using a javascript variable into HTML. You can set your select id using plain javascript into a `<script>` tag.